# Dart/Flutter auth implementation

Tags: cookies, authentication, dart, flutter

I am working on a sample Flutter mobile application.

Does Flutter / Dart have any http libraries that support persisting secure cookies.

Example use case ( guessing it should be pretty common use case): User logs in once and the application should be able to use secure cookie from successful sign-in until session gets expire/ user signs out.

On android, OkHttp supports persisting cookies and sending those persisted cookies whenever client (application) makes a request to the backend.

What is the best way to acheive that in Flutter?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to flutter, it is pure dart but :

For cookies, there's dart:io with [`Cookie`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-io/Cookie-class.html) class
There's the `boolean secure` property and `boolean httpOnly` you can set.

As for Http connections, you can simply use dart:http's [`HttpClient`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html). 
**OR** you can use flutter's [`createHttpClient`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/HttpOverrides/createHttpClient.html) method which is recomended by flutter for testing purpose (mock) ; as stated [here](https://flutter.io/networking/)

Answer (score 1):

I've published a small flutter library called [requests](https://github.com/jossef/requests) to assist with cookie-aware http requests (with the assistance of [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences))

- as of now, it uses [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) which is not the best practice (security-wise) to store sensitive data (session-ids etc) [Issue #1](https://github.com/jossef/requests/issues/1)

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  requests: ^1.0.0
```

Usage:

```
import 'package:requests/requests.dart';

// ...

// this will persist cookies
await Requests.post("https://example.com/api/v1/login", body: {"username":"...", "password":"..."} ); 

// this will re-use the persisted cookies
dynamic data = await Requests.get("https://example.com/api/v1/stuff", json: true);
```